# Model validation with respect to action being taken over entity being validated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

How can we validate data based on action being taken over particular entity? What other more advanced alternatives are there to data annotations model validation? Possibly pluggable into Asp.net MVC and WebAPI, so validation is still being done automatically.

### Example

Suppose a user join form of a web application.

```
public class User
{
    // required when providing user as input
    // not provided when creating new instance
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // required when user joins and of specific format AND IS UNIQUE based on data store users
    // optional when providing user as input
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Maybe object inheritance could help but as much as I think of it, inheritance would only be as a hack. Base class would hardly have any properties and we could end up with several extremely similar (properties) classes but with different annotations just to use data annotations. And that's not good.

### Desired implementation

I was thinking of validation based on action being taken over particular entity. So we'd be able to define something like:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(Action = ValidationAction.Provide)] // or whatever action we'd define
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(Action = ValidationAction.Create)]
    [IsUnique(Action = ValidationAction.Create)] // custom DataAnnotations validator
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Asp.net MVC and WebAPI controller actions would require some sort of attribute to provide information what's being done with particular entities a parameters

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateForAction("user", ValidationAction.Create)]
[ValidateForAction("user.InvitedBy", ValidationAction.Provide)]
public ActionResult Join(User user)
{
    ...
}
```

or set it uniformly for all parameters (and their object entities in subtrees)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateForAction(ValidationAction.Create)]
public ActionResult Join(User user)
{
    ...
}
```

When `ValidateForActionAttribute` isn't present on controller action validation should only check validation action independent annotations (like the `EmailAddressAttribute` set above on my entity example).

A similar example could be Stackoverflow scenario of adding an answer where posted answer details would be validated by create action, and related question entity (a property inside an answer) would be validated per *provide* action because we'd mainly just need its `Id`.

#### Is there any such validation library? Anybody done something similar?

### How would you go about doing such validation?

Comment: I guess you will have to create your own validation class here.

Comment: The short answer is, you shouldn't.  If there are properties you are not using in your view, then you should create a new ViewModel for that contains only the properties you need.  In your case, it would not include an email property, thus there is nothing to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like its similar to a requiredif validator where the validation is dependent upon another property. However, model validation will not work here since the model is "supposed" to be independent of views or controllers.

Assume though that you have a view model associated with individual actions on a controller, then the view model could use data annotations consistent with the requirements of the view. See [ASP.Net MVC and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739385/asp-net-mvc-and-mvvm) for more detail on the MVVM pattern.

One last comment with regard to the Id. Not sure a Required attribute will work since the default for an int is a valid value. Perhaps a regex? ([1-9]|[0-9]{2,10})

```
public class RegistrationController

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Provide(UserProvideViewModel user)
    {
         ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Join(UserJoinViewModel user)
    {
         ...
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(UserProvideViewModel_Validation))]
public partial class UserProvideViewModel : User
{
    // properties unique to the view model
}

public class UserProvideViewModel_Validation
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^([1-9]|\d{2,10})$")]
     public Id { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(UserJoinViewModel_Validation))]
public partial class UserJoinViewModel : User
{
    // properties unique to the view model
}

public class UserJoinViewModel_Validation
{
     [Required]
     [EmailAddress]
     public Email { get; set; }
}
```